# Grails Asset Pipeline @font-face src url

Tags: css, grails, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I just started a new Grails project (Grails v2.4.2) and it is my first time using the Asset Pipeline plugin. I managed to get it working without much issue until I noticed the fonts were not displaying correctly.

I figured that the issue was the @font-face url in the css did not have the correct path. The only way that I could get it to work was to put the full path to the files into the css which was, for example:

```
src: url('/ProjectName/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
```

The font files are all in the grails-app/assets/fonts folder and the css files are in the grails-app/assets/stylesheet folders.

Is there a better way to reference the font files from the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue for me was caused by a bug in the version of the Asset plugin that was bundled with Grails 2.4.2. This error will only show up for people using Windows PC's

> Illegal character in path at index 0: \/../

Once I went from asset-pipeline:1.9.4 to asset-pipeline:1.9.6 the error went away

The error is discussed [here:](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/issues/131)